# How can I format a two row string so that items of the bottom row line up with items of the top row in java

Tags: java, string, formatting, format

So I have something set up like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fun = ("3000.05 500 6000.987 70 8000.00");
    String lame = ("3 5 6 7 8");
    String total = (fun + "\n" + lame);
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

How can I format the total string so that when it prints it prints like this:

```
3000.05 500 6000.987 70 8000.00  
      3   5        6  7       8
```

I've been looking forever and can't seem to find what i'm looking for.  I'm just trying to right align each part of the bottom string to the farthest part of the top string.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I actually didn't understand what you want to achieve. Is it to right align each substring with the first value on the it?

Comment: You could format your numbers with String.format and calculate the format string with something like String.valueOf(3000.05).length().

Comment: Also your example is confusing because there are more dashes than the length between the numbers, i.e. `3000.05` should have 6 dashes and then the number 3, shouldn't it?

Comment: dambros- The goal is to right align each bottom number with the last integer of the number above it. The problem is I don't know how long the top numbers will be due to the nature of my program

Comment: Horrible, roundabout way of tackling this; and a good amount of polishing required.  But enough to get started with: https://ideone.com/bUUEb6

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop to go through each position on the string and create a new String to store what you are looking for. Ex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String fun = ("3000.05 500 6000.987 70 8000.00");

String newStringToBePrinted="";
for(char c: fun){
 if (!(c == ' '|| c == '.')){
  String ch = c+"";
   newStringToBePrinted+= ch;
} else{
  newStringToBePrinted+="-";
 }
}

String total = (fun + "\n" + newStringToBePrinted);


System.out.println(total);
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Respectfully - this code looks like it just replaces spaces and periods in the original string with -'s. Could you please clarify how you'd apply this to the OP's problem?

Comment: So, from what I am seeing, your goal is to create a string that only contains non-zero numerical values?

Comment: Ooh i get it, give me a moment I will get u ur code

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this with (moderately) readable Stream code. The below method will work, but it's a bit ugly because AFAIK Java 8 does not yet have a clean 'zip' function for streams.

As well, because of the way String.format() works, I had to pad the first thing in the list separately, which is also kind of yucky, but I couldn't quickly think of a way to make it all fit.

```
    private String formatStringPairs(String firstLine, String secondLine, String delimiter) {
        String[] firstLineArray = firstLine.split(delimiter);
        String[] secondLineArray = secondLine.split(delimiter);

        String formattedStringPairs =
            String.format("%" + firstLineArray[0].length() + "s", secondLineArray[0]) +
            IntStream.range(1, firstLineArray.length)
            .mapToObj(index -> String.format("%" + (firstLineArray[index].length() + 1) + "s", secondLineArray[index]))
            .reduce("", String::concat);
        return firstLine + "\n" + formattedStringPairs;
    }
```

I look forward to seeing someone post a cleaner and better way!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I believe temp is the recreation of your variable lame but the code would be the same.

```
package funTest;

public class funT {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fun = ("3000.05 500 6000.987 70 8000.00");
    String s2 = new String(fun);
    char first=' ';
    String temp="";
    for (int i = 0;i < s2.length(); i++){
        System.out.println("Should be: 3,5,6,7,8");
    //gets first    
     if (i!=0){
         if (s2.charAt(i)==' '){
             first=s2.charAt(i+1);
         }
     }else{
         first=s2.charAt(i); 
     }
     System.out.println("First = "+first);

     /////

     //add spaces
     if (s2.charAt(i)!=' '){
         temp+=' ';
     }

     if (i<s2.length()-1&&s2.charAt(i+1)==' '){
         temp+=first;
     } else if (i==s2.length()-1){
         temp+=first;
     }
    }
    temp = temp.substring(1);

    System.out.println(s2+"\n"+temp);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so tldr. Use the `.format()` method of `PrintStream (for byte streams)` or `PrintWriter (for char streams)`

Luckily `System.out` is one of these objects. Documentation for format can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

Here is a nice demonstration of using `.format()` I mentioned for your purpose, this code assumes the two strings have an equal number of numbers separated by whitespace. It also assumes that the `second-row item length will be <= in length to its' first-row counterpart`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fun = "3000.05 500 6000.987 70 8000.00";
    String lame = "3 5 6 7 8";

    String[] funs = fun.split(" ");
    String[] lames = lame.split(" ");

    for(String s : funs)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s\t", s);
    }

    System.out.printf("%n");

    for(int i = 0; i < lames.length; i++) //use index iterator so we can get le funz
    {
        System.out.printf("%" + funs[i].length() + "s\t", lames[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("%n");

}
```

Output:

```
run:
3000.05 500 6000.987    70  8000.00 
      3   5        6     7        8 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

To improve this code more It might be possible to associate the first row and second row in a Map type object, and then when printing: set the padding size
to the size of the entry key or value which has the greatest length. Also add a handler for empty entries.